# How to access HTML element using XPath in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, xpath

I am stuck with as issue of accessing HTML element in IE using XPath in Javascript?
I already tried with selectNodes() method but its for XML only, it does not
work for XPath of HTML element.

```
document.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
var mydoc=document.loadXML(document);
var nodes=mydoc.selectNodes("//input[@name='action']");
```

But its not returning any element.
Can anyone suggest me how to access HTML element in IE by XPath using Javascript?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be due to the namespace associated with Html elements.just a guess.

Comment: @Furqan : Can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: the Html rendered in browser has the html tag like this, <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >, the xmlns attribute specifies the namespace that all html tags belong to , so whenever you want to access some html element, you can do by specifying Namespace before tagname i-e "//xs:input".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also like this solution to add xpath support for HTML in IE:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/html-xpath/

This has the benefit of unifying the API between IE and other browsers, as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following ,

> Browsers can use the following to get
>   all elements with a given tag,
>   regardless of namespace, if the
>   document is served as
>   application/xhtml+xml or other XML
>   type:

```
    var titles = document.getElementsByTagNameNS("*","input[@name='action']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Wicked Good XPath:
https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/

It is the smallest and fastest JavaScript-based XPath library and maintained by Google.