# Get elements using javascript and XPATH in internet Explorer

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer

I am writing a tool in C# which has WebBrowser in it and it uses IE 8. Now I want to write a java script which I can run on the webpage inside the WebBrowser to get some elements.

As document.evaluate does not work on Internet Explorer, is there any other way I can achieve it? I have seen some other similar posts however they are related to writing the javascripts directly into HTML using some libraries. I am new to all this so can someone please tell me is there any way I can achieve this through the C# code?

Comment: Have you tried looking up “IE XPath JavaScript”? Although IE doesn’t support `document.evaluate`, it does, as usual, have its own XPath API. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402111/how-to-access-html-element-using-xpath-in-ie8) might help.

Comment: @minitech: thanks for the quick reply.. will look into the link.

Comment: I already have looked at that API but could not figure out how to use it through the C# code.. any pointers?

Comment: It will work in JavaScript. Are you looking for C#? If so, this really has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: <code>
HtmlElement head = webBrowserPageViewer.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement javascript = webBrowserPageViewer.Document.CreateElement("script");
            javascript.SetAttribute("src", "html-xpath.js");
            mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement scriptElement = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)javascript.DomElement;
            scriptElement.text = <javascript>;
            head.AppendChild(javascript);
</code>


Am looking for Javascript.. Is this the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Google's Wicked-good-xpath library worked.
https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/

So to explain it, as its a webbrowser control, we need to add js file contents in the script tag of the current html in the WebBrowser and then call the install method as explained in your script.

In case if you are shipping your javascript, then you may need to include the wicked-good-xpath libraries file contents or as per standard way ship the library with your script and add its reference in your code. (In my case I was supposed to send only one js file so added the library contents in the same file)

Thanks minitech for the pointers.!